# What type of Architecture is used by spring roo+vaadin?

Tags: spring, vaadin, spring-roo

After searching about spring roo using vaadin plugin , i can't find what is the appropriate architecture is used within.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the architecture there isn't that well thought so I wouldn't invest that much for it. Pivotal itself has pretty much stopped investing on it so I'd be surprised if we (I work at Vaadin) would invest it either. Instead of Roo I suggest to look at Spring Boot. Very different approach, but the at least one goal is kind of the same: to get started quickly with new projects.